# How do I make entire div a mailto link?

Tags: html, css

Trying to make a responsive website for mobile/pc, and not sure what the best way is to design a mailto link.

Tried the answers found on StackOverflow and haven't been able to fill the div area with the link, aka make the entire space clickable.

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: #5D6063;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.contact {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

#contact a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='page'>
    <div class='section contact'>
      <a href="mailto:email@gmail.com?Subject=Website%20Contact" target="_blank">Contact Me</a>
    </div>
```

I was expecting the `#contact a {" to fill the ".contact` div, but it's not, and I don't know how to just make the whole `.contact` div a link without screwing up the responsive styling.

Comment: wrap div with the a tag

Comment: I don't see any elements with an id `contact` in your example code

Comment: Since HTML5, A tags can be used as block tags. You could use `<a class='section contact'....`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following I just change the #contact a to .contact a and few code adjustment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Click Able Div Container</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;  
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 1.8em;
            color: #5D6063; 
        }

        .page {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .section {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }


        .contact {
            background-color: #bdbdbd;
        }

        .contact a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 150px 0;
            text-align: center;
        }       
    </style>
</head>
<body >
 <div class='page'>
    <div class='section contact'>
        <a href="mailto:email@gmail.com?Subject=Website%20Contact" target="_blank">Contact Me</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Actually I just realized my email address is in the code, I'm going to edit it out of mine - could you do the same? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `div` with `a` tag to make the entire div block act as a link.

```
 <a href="mailto:test@example.com?Subject=Website%20Contact" 
   target="_blank">
  <div class='section contact'>
      Contact Me
  </div>
 </a>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked as well. Actually I just realized my email address is in the code, I'm going to edit it out of mine - could you do the same? Thank you!